# How to convert data with many rows into one row ?(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In my master thesis,I'm trying to find the different kind of User Behavior based on how a person uses his mobile applications.

My dataset is .csv file (log file).I have data of one mounth application usage from many Android users.

For each user, I collected his daily interactions related to the way he uses mobile apps such :   `Name of used App,Category App, Time of use, Frequency of use ,Duration of use.` My data set consists of 9632 lines distributed over 67 users .

```py
d = [[1,   '2020-09-10'  ,'evening',    'Settings',     'System tool',        1,          3.436],
    [1,   '2020-09-11'  ,'afternoon',   'Calendar',    'Calendar ',          5,          9.965],
    [1,   '2020-09-11'  ,'afternoon',   'Contacts',    'Phone_and_SMS',      7 ,         2.606],
    [2,   '2020-09-11'  ,'afternoon',   'Facebook',    'Social',             15 ,        50.799],
    [2,   '2020-09-11'  ,'afternoon',   'clock',       'System tool',        2,          5.223],
    [3 ,  '2020-11-18'  ,'morning',    'Contacts',    'Phone_and_SMS',       3 ,         1.726],
    [3 ,  '2020-11-18'  ,'morning',     'Google',    'Productivity',         1 ,         4.147],
    [3 ,  '2020-11-18'  ,'morning',    'Instagram',    'Social',             1 ,         0.501],
    [4 ,  '2020-11-18'  ,'morning',    'Truecaller',   'Communication',      1,          1.246],
    [4 ,  '2020-11-18'  ,'night',      'Instagram',    'Social',             7 ,        103.774]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['UserId',  'Date',    'Part_of_day',    'Apps',         'Category',        'Frequency',      'Duration_ToT'])
```

To be clear, here is an example of dataframe:

```
UserId  Date    Part_of_day    Apps         Category        Frequency      Duration_ToT
    1   2020-09-10  evening    Settings     System tool        1          3.436
    1   2020-09-11  afternoon   Calendar    Calendar           5          9.965
    1   2020-09-11  afternoon   Contacts    Phone_and_SMS      7          2.606
    2   2020-09-11  afternoon   Facebook    Social             15         50.799
    2   2020-09-11  afternoon   clock       System tool        2          5.223
    3   2020-11-18  morning    Contacts    Phone_and_SMS       3          1.726
    3   2020-11-18  morning     Google    Productivity         1          4.147
    3   2020-11-18  morning    Instagram    Social             1          0.501
    4   2020-11-18  morning    Truecaller   Communication      1          1.246
    4   2020-11-18  night      Instagram    Social             7         103.774
```

As our aim is to discover the different type of behavior "Clusters of behavior",I would like to know how to reduce many rows of used APPs into one Apps used per user? to set the entries (input ) for ML algorithmes like K-Means.
I am trying to reduce dataframe rows to represent each user by one row .

I've looked into getting top 5 used apps by frequency and duration, is that true or should i try other thing. How should i do ?
Please help !

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: do you want a column with a list of used apps per user or a columns per app with boolean values? it would be better if you can you show us your expected output

Comment: I  want a column with a list of most  used apps per user  .

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: No idea of the output data, I was trying to represent the interactions of a user (500 lines) by a single line, it's possible!

Comment: use `df1 = df.groupby(['UserId', 'Apps'])['Frequency'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False);
apps_freq_top5 = df1.reset_index().groupby('UserId')['Apps'].agg(list).str[:5]` to find the top freq used apps for every userid.

Comment: Why do you want to make it a single row? @ab20225

Comment: I will use k-means afterwards, with these data I have no interpretable result

Comment: What do you intend to find?

Comment: group of users by used Apps

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas `groupby` & `sort`
It first `groups` the dataframe for `each user`. Now for each group, it sort the dataframe by `Frequency` and `Duration_ToT` and takes first 5 elements.

```py
df.groupby(['UserId']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by=['Frequency', 'Duration_ToT'], ascending=False).head(5))
```